# My access 2010 database displays parameter query dialogue boxes instead of getting the values from my where clause

Tags: ms-access, parameters, where-clause, clause

I have a database that I've been building and from time to time all of the queries that have paraeters defined by text boxes on a form (driven by the where clauses) do not work. Instead, Access asks me for values in the form of parameter dialogue boxes for all the quires set up to work off the form. I've run into this several times and I've stripped out the last change that I've made and it all functions as designed (until now).

The question is - what is causing this? It's like none of the where clauses function.

Thanks for any input....

Comment: Like Remou states post your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL would be good however at a guess you probably need to specificly declare the type of the paramaters either by using the paramaters dialog box (Not sure where it is in 2010, we are still using 2003 here!) or by using the PARAMATERS keyword (from memory... may not be exactly correct...)

```
PARAMATERS [forms]![someForm]![someTextBox] DateTime, 
           [forms]![someForm]![someComboBox] Decimal;
SELECT x,y from tblZ 
WHERE x=[forms]![someForm]![someTextBox] 
AND y=[forms]![someForm]![someComboBox];
```